# form_for links to another controller Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a form with action that point to another controller but it does not work

My form :

```
<%= form_for([@product,@product.subjects.build]) do |s| %>
```

The form is rendered in the /products/show_sujet.html.erb

But i have this error :

unknown attribute: product_id

I don't know what to do ?

Subject.rb

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product
end
```

Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :subjects
validates :ean,:marque,:description, presence: true
end
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: can u add from where u are rendering your form...? and also your show_subject method..?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't migrated your database after creating the Subject model. If you did, find the migration that creates the `subjects` table and make sure it adds the column for `product_id`. If you don't have this you'll need to create a migration for this with:

```
rails g migration addProductIdColumnToSubject product_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

This will take care of the `unknown attribute: product_id` error.

Now, if you're using Rails 4 you'll need to add this attribute to your [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) in your `subjects` controller.

In [Rails 3](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class), you'd need to add `:product_id` to the `attr_accessible` declaration in the `Subject` model.

Comment: Thank you Diego !

It works but why do i have to add the product_id ? Why rails don't add it automatically when i run rake db:migrate ?

For example i have another table comments which is associated to another table post and works fine without comment_id in the migrate file...

Any explanations ?

Comment: This will explain it nicely: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thks Diego, i will check it ;)